# Error while connecting to mysql database from php

Tags: php, mysql

I have recently started exploring free hosting sites where they provide free mysql and php.

I have created a database and trying to connect to the database from php script. But while running the php. I am getting following error :

Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'a1696486_test '@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home/a1696486/public_html/myphp/test1.php on line 2

Warning: mysql_select_db() [function.mysql-select-db]: Access denied for user 'a1696486'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/a1696486/public_html/myphp/test1.php on line 3

Any idea whats the problem ?

Regards,
Shankar

Comment: Wrong user or password? Can you show the code you use to connect? why are there 2 different users?

Comment: try root user. if works then problem in creating user or granted roles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this issue on our dedicated servers, and the solution for me is to provide the fully qualified domain name rather than 'localhost'. For exmaple, my connection is:

```
mysqli_connect('dedi81.jnb1.host-h.net', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
```

Where even though localhost is the same as dedi81.jnb1.host-h.net (MySQL server and web server on one machine) I - for some reason - cannot use 'localhost'.

Another issue may be that on the hosting company you're with, they have not granted to you the correct permissions, or that there is indeed an error with the username and / or password.

You can also try and substitute 'localhost' with the IP address of the MySQL machine.

Kind regards,
Simon

Comment: The host should be right, as he can connect. It's the user who's either wrong or without the sufficient privileges.

Comment: @Damien Pirsy - Good observation, you're correct. Silly me for not seeing that, and based on your comment, it can only be an incorrect username or password, or that the user has no permissions granted to him.